# Optional parameters in route - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have in routes:

```
Route::get('feed/{type?}/{first?}/{second?}/{third?}', ['as' => 'feed', 'uses' => 'PostController@feed']);
```

I try pass the URL (get):

```
http://localhost/feed/area/48.1486/17.1077/km
```

PostController:

```
    public function feed(Request $request)
{
    switch ($request->route('type')) {
        case 'area':
            if (!$request->route('first') || !$request->route('second')) {
                break;
            }

            $third = ($request->route('third')) ? $request->route('third') : 'km';
            $posts = $this->post->getNumpostsArea($request,30,(float)$request->route('first'),(float)$request->route('second'),$third='km');

            $feed = Feed::make();
            $feed->title = siteSettings('siteName');
            $feed->description = siteSettings('description');
            $feed->logo = asset('/static/img/favicon.ico');
            $feed->link = $request->fullUrl();
            $feed->setDateFormat('carbon'); // 'datetime', 'timestamp' or 'carbon'
            $feed->pubdate = $posts[0]->created_at;
            $feed->lang = 'en';
            $feed->setShortening(true);
            $feed->setTextLimit(100);
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                $feed->add($post->title . ' (' . $post->distance . $third . ')', $post->user->fullname, route('posts.main', ['id' => $post->id, 'slug' => $post->slug]), $post->approved_at, parseDown($post->description), parseDown($post->content));
            }
            return $feed->render('atom');

            break;
...
```

I get error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Can you help me little what I am doing bad? Thinking why I am out of routes.
Thank you.

Comment: I would definitely take those `.` out of your route/URI and use a method in your controller to move the decimal point and get the correct value

Comment: The same error without decimal point. No difference

Comment: I assume the `feed` method exists in PostController?

Comment: I update my question. PostController included

Comment: Could you give the output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: Sure https://ctrlv.it/id/16434/86654886

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that route isn't listed in there?

Comment: Sorry seems problem with cache. Solved now. Thank you for assistance.

Comment: Was just about to write an answer about that haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with cache. No issue with code.